# Determinant of metric tensor

Tags: metric-spaces, determinant

My doubt aroused when I saw this formula:

$\partial_i g = g \, \, g^{ab} \ \partial_i g_{ab} $

where $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor. Now I think the determinant is invariant under change of basis. 
But, as it is seen from this formula, it is not invariant under coordinate displacement. Why? Isn't there a change of basis, function of the coordinates, that translates the metric tensor, say $\phi (x,x'): g_{ab} (x) \mapsto g_{ab} (x')$ ?

(I am not interested in this particular function, I just want to know what am I misunderstanding. I don't study mathematics so please forgive me).

Comment: If you perform a change of basis, a change of basis matrix determinant will appear in that formula with g

Comment: Wouldn't it be something like $\det g_{ab}(x')  = \det \big[ C^{-1} (x,x') \, g_{ab}(x) \, C(x,x') \big] = \det^{-1} C(x,x') \, \det  g_{ab}(x) \, \det C(x,x') =  det  g_{ab}(x) $

Comment: The change is basis matrices aren't necessarily inverses of one another. It's​ more like the equivalent of obtaining a Jacobian matrix in integration. The metric components most generally depend on local coordinates and so translating them doesn't necessarily mean it will have the same determinant